# Loading data to neo4j from XML using py2neo

Tags: python, xml, neo4j, py2neo

Im trying to load data to neo4j db from xml file using py2neo

this python script works fine but its too slow since Im adding the nodes first then the relationships with two exceptions handlers. besides that the XML file size is around 200MB.

Im wondering if there is faster way to perform this task?

XML file:

```
<Persons>
    <person>
        <id>XA123</id>
        <first_name>Adam</first_name>
        <last_name>John</last_name>
        <phone>01-12322222</phone>
    </person>
    <person>
        <id>XA7777</id>
        <first_name>Anna</first_name>
        <last_name>Watson</last_name>
        <relationship>
            <type>Friends</type>
            <to>XA123</to>
        </relationship>
    </person>
</Persons>
```

python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from xml.dom import minidom
from py2neo import Graph, Node, Relationship, authenticate


graph = Graph("http://localhost:7474/db/data/")
authenticate("localhost:7474", "neo4j", "admin")

xml_file = open("data.xml")
xml_doc = minidom.parse(xml_file)
persons = xml_doc.getElementsByTagName('person')

# Adding Nodes
for person in persons:
    ID_ = person.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.data
    fName = person.getElementsByTagName('first_name')[0].firstChild.data
    lName = person.getElementsByTagName('last_name')[0].firstChild.data

    # not every person has phone number
    try:
        phone = person.getElementsByTagName('phone')[0].firstChild.data
    except IndexError:
        phone = "None"

    label = "Person"
    node = Node(label, ID=ID_, LastName=fName, FirstName=lName, Phone=phone)
    graph.create(node)


# Adding Relationships
for person in persons:
    ID_ = person.getElementsByTagName('id')[0].firstChild.data

    label = "Person"
    node1 = graph.find_one(label, property_key="ID", property_value=ID_)

    # relationships
    try:
        has_relations = person.getElementsByTagName('relationship')
        for relation in has_relations:
            node2 = graph.find_one(label,
                                   property_key="ID",
                                   property_value=relation.getElementsByTagName('to')[0].firstChild.data)

            relationship = Relationship(node1,
                                        relation.getElementsByTagName('type')[0].firstChild.data, node2)
            graph.create(relationship)
    except IndexError:
        continue
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the time needed to load the data into neo4j has significantly reduced by using unique property constraints for a specific label.

```
graph.cypher.execute("CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Person) ASSERT n.ID IS UNIQUE")
```