# parsing XML file depends on tags which may or may not be existed

Tags: python, xml

Im trying to parse an XML file depends on a tag which may or may not be existed !

how I can avoid this IndexError without using exception handler ?

python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from xml.dom import minidom


doc = minidom.parse("Data.xml")

persons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person")

for person in persons:
    print(person.getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].firstChild.data)
```

Data.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<obo>
    <Persons>
        <person>
            <id>XA123</id>
            <first_name>Adam</first_name>
            <last_name>John</last_name>
            <phone>01-12322222</phone>
        </person>
        <person>
            <id>XA7777</id>
            <first_name>Anna</first_name>
            <last_name>Watson</last_name>
            <relationship>
                <type>Friends</type>
                <to>XA123</to>
            </relationship>
            <!--<phone>01-12322222</phone>-->
        </person>
    </Persons>
</obo>
```

and I get an IndexError:

```
01-12322222
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XML->Neo4j-try.py", line 29, in <module>
    print(person.getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].firstChild.data)
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Why dont you want to use exception handler? I think it is the good way to do that. You can usr If-else clauses to make sure whether a level exists. But this way is not really dynamical. You may not know how many level it has.

Comment: cos I have big xml file, which - I think -  will take long time to parse if there are many exceptions handlers plz check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37022525/loading-data-to-neo4j-from-xml-using-py2neo)

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check whether current person has phone data, and proceed further only if it has. Also, it is slightly better to store the result of `getElementsByTagName()` in a variable to avoid doing the same query repeatedly, especially when the actual XML has a lot more content in each `person` element :

```
for person in persons:
    phones = person.getElementsByTagName("phone")
    if phones:
        print(phones[0].firstChild.data)
```

Answer (score -1):

it is giving error because if any person does not have phone then

```
from xml.dom import minidom
doc = minidom.parse("Data.xml")
persons = doc.getElementsByTagName("person")
for person in persons:
    if person.getElementsByTagName("phone"):
        print(person.getElementsByTagName("phone")[0].firstChild.data)
```